How to make langchain RAG chain with history message return the message id after saving to sql db?
I have a chain that's like this:
qa_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt)
rag_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever, qa_chain)
history_aware_rag_chain = RunnalbeWithMessageHistory(chain, get_history_message)

The get_history_message returns a SQLMessageHistory object where messages are read/write from db. In the SQLMessageHistory class, the add_message function is like this:
def add_message(self, message: BaseMessage) -> None:
    db_message = self.message_class(session_id=self.session_id)
    self.session.add(db_message)
    self.session.flush(db_message)
    message.id = db_message.id

But the history_aware_rag_chain is returning a dictionary instead of the original AIMessage object. Is it possible to make the id from db to be returned in the final chain?
